# How to access hadoop cluster (unix) from client windows machine

Tags: hadoop, user-management

I have virtual hadoop cluster and client to hadoop is running on windows machine. When I am submitting mapred job I am getting org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied access=EXECUTE, inode="":jakub:supergroup:rwx------- as it runs under windows user.

I tried to disabl those checks by setting dfs.permissions to false. Seems that didn't help.

When I try to submit the job under the user hadoop is runnig on cluster I get:  User: XXX is not allowed to impersonate jakub.

This is related to user management on hadoop. Do I miss something important here? I is my development machine so the easest solution wins.

Thanks

Comment: what windows client you're using to submit jobs to a unix-installed hadoop?

Comment: Regular java process running on Windows machine using Hadoop-client lib.  Nothing special.  Hadoop 2.4.1 brings new property  for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it is not the best solution but I figure it out:

1) created "windows" user on linux machine

2) add that user to usergroup under which hadoop is running

3) hdfs-site.xml add prperty for dfs.permissions.supergroup to usergroup hadoop is running under

That solved the problem for me. I do not claim that it is the best, definetevly not a propper user management.